# GZipStream corrupts file if i pack it in parts (Flush doesn't work)

Tags: c#, flush, gzipstream

I've tried to use this code to compress a file in parts

```
using (var fsIn = new FileStream("test.avi", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var fsOut = new FileStream("test.avi.gz", FileMode.Create))
    {
        var buf = new byte[1024 * 1024];

        using (var gzip = new GZipStream(fsOut, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var readCount = fsIn.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                if (readCount <= 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                gzip.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                gzip.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but i've got corrupted file after decompression. This code works

```
using (var fsIn = new FileStream("test.avi", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var fsOut = new FileStream("test.avi.gz", FileMode.Create))
    {
        var buf = new byte[1024*1024];

        while (true)
        {
            var readCount = fsIn.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            if (readCount <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            // This string was transferred into "while" cycle
            using (var gzip = new GZipStream(fsOut, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
            {
                gzip.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why gzip.Flush() doesn't work? Why only gzip.Close() works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yuo need to know that `gzip.Flush();` is not working

From [MSDN - GZipStream.Flush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.flush.aspx) :

> The current implementation of this method does not flush the internal
>   buffer. The internal buffer is flushed when the object is disposed.

Comment: Hm. The built-in method summary tells the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

`new GZipStream(fsOut, CompressionMode.Compress, true)` leaves the stream open after disposing, you should change the last parameter to `false`.

[GZipStream Constructor (Stream, CompressionMode, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ck2z1y.aspx)

> `leaveOpen`
>   Type: `System.Boolean`
>   `true` to leave the stream open after disposing the `GZipStream` object; otherwise, `false`.

Also [Flush()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.flush.aspx) has no effects in GZipStream

> The current implementation of this method does not flush the internal
>   buffer. The internal buffer is flushed when the object is disposed.

Comment: If i'll write "false" then it will not work, because i need to left fsOut opened in second version. And the default value is false.

Answer (score 0):

File is compressed properly. in fact it turns out that the file contains a set of compressed files. Archives number equal to the number parts. At each new iteration, a new file and appended to the file. 
decision

You need to specify the length of the packaging after the packaging and before burning to file.

Just like that:

Compress:

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(compressedPart.Length).CopyTo(blockToWrite, 4);
```

In decompression read this length and choose part of the file is equal to this length for decompression.